# cocos2D iphone v3.3 setBlendFunc deprecated

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, deprecated

In v3.0 I used setBlendFunc. Now in 3.3 this method is warned as deprecated. What should be used instead ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is one example, when i refactored my code :

```
//        [_firstSprite setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc) {GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE}]; // deprecated

 _firstSprite.blendMode    = [CCBlendMode blendModeWithOptions:@{
        CCBlendFuncSrcColor : @(GL_SRC_ALPHA),
        CCBlendFuncDstColor : @(GL_ONE),}
];
```

you will have to research for your specifics, but that is the general direction to look into.

Comment: That's my answer. Thank you.